# Why do I get an error when I select multiple values across multiple columns using IN but not when using = operator?

Tags: sql, db2

I want to get a specific subset of data from my table based on values I specify across 3 columns.

The following SQL is returning the expected results (but only 1 record from the table).

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (col1, col2, col3) = (value1, value2, value3);
```

Example of results:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value 1 | value 2 | value 3 | value 4 |

Now all I want to do is return multiple records from the table with specified values for col1, 2 and 3.

I changed the above query as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (col1, col2, col3) IN ((value1, value2, value3), (value5, value6, value7));
```

I was expecting 2 rows from my table to return. An example of my expected results:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value 1 | value 2 | value 3 | value 4 |
| value 5 | value 6 | value 7 | value 8 |

But my query gives me the following error: *SQL Error [42601]: [SQL0104] Token 'value1' was not valid. Valid tokens: (.*

Please help with correct syntax.

Comment: Your syntax is fine, SQL standard optional features. But it seems as DB2 doesn't support it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple rows to code you it must be preceded by a `values` keyword like below

```
SELECT *
  FROM myTable
 WHERE (col1, col2, col3) IN (
  values (value1, value2, value3), (value5, value6, value7)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE (col1, col2, col3) IN (value1, value2, value3)
   OR (col1, col2, col3) IN (value5, value6, value7);
```

This one isn't using the (optional) Feature "T051, Row types"

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM myTable t
JOIN ( VALUES (value1, value2, value3)
            , (value5, value6, value7) ) x (col1, col2, col3)
    USING (col1, col2, col3)
```